# Marker-controlled watershed segmentation

Tags: lidr

I am trying to do a marker-controlled watershed segmentation. `lidR` package is updated and `mcwatershed()` has been removed in the latest release. How can I apply marker-controlled segmentation? Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

`mcwatershed()` relied on the `imager` package that is an orphaned package on CRAN. This generated troublesshooting on CRAN thus the dependency to `imager` has been removed. It used the function `watershed()` from `imager`. You can start there.

The source code has only been commented so you can still read the [original sources](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/blob/544441c7b8893c5f3bf4ece27c2b177863f859ab/R/algorithm-its.R#L452) to help you.

Comment: Also, `imager::watershed()`'s been called from [`ForestTools::mcws()`](https://github.com/andrew-plowright/ForestTools/blob/master/R/mwcs.R) for some time, though I don't think this was documented until April 2021.